# Xamarin Forms IOS build not copying anything to bin debug folder

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

Main and Android projects copy to the bin .exe and pub files fine, the IOS build fails.

Bundle Resource 'bin\iPhone\Debug\FloridaPlatApp.iOS.exe' not found on disk (should be at 'C:\Users\tim\source\repos\FloridaPlatApp\FloridaPlatApp\FloridaPlatApp.iOS\bin\iPhone\Debug\FloridaPlatApp.iOS.exe')

Bundle Resource 'bin\iPhone\Debug\FloridaPlatApp.iOS.pdb' not found on disk (should be at 'C:\Users\tim\source\repos\FloridaPlatApp\FloridaPlatApp\FloridaPlatApp.iOS\bin\iPhone\Debug\FloridaPlatApp.iOS.pdb')

Done building project "FloridaPlatApp.csproj".
------ Build started: Project: FloridaPlatApp.iOS, Configuration: Debug iPhoneSimulator ------
Executing SayHello Task to establish a connection to a Remote Server.
Properties:
SessionId=a2cc5b6c4a00255b6b8f8f64333fa9e42f71a47XXXXXXXXXXX1fc6047d71d,
Addresss=19x.x.x.x,
SshPort=22,
TcpPort=53159,
User=Tim Maxey,
AppName=FloridaPlatApp.iOS,
VisualStudioProcessId=xxx8,
ContinueOnDisconnected=False
Detected signing identity:

```
Bundle Id: com.tmaida.floridaplatapp
App Id: com.tmaida.floridaplatapp
```

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.Shared.targets(452,3): error :   Bundle Resource 'bin\iPhone\Debug\FloridaPlatApp.iOS.exe' not found on disk (should be at 'C:\Users\tim\source\repos\FloridaPlatApp\FloridaPlatApp\FloridaPlatApp.iOS\bin\iPhone\Debug\FloridaPlatApp.iOS.exe')
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.Shared.targets(452,3): error :
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.Shared.targets(452,3): error :   Bundle Resource 'bin\iPhone\Debug\FloridaPlatApp.iOS.pdb' not found on disk (should be at 'C:\Users\tim\source\repos\FloridaPlatApp\FloridaPlatApp\FloridaPlatApp.iOS\bin\iPhone\Debug\FloridaPlatApp.iOS.pdb')

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.Shared.targets(452,3): error :

Comment: BTW: I have already unloaded projects, deleted bin and obj folders, reloaded Nugets, this app use to run on the iPhone. Updates did something to create this?

Comment: May i ask what command you used to build? And Could this help [Pair to Mac for Xamarin.iOS development](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/)

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT yes I am paired to a mac and a few weeks ago I was working on this app and already successfully deployed/debugged to my iphone 12. In fact app still on the iphone 12. I just compile/run from Visual Studio Windows. 2022. Moved to a new Laptop and installed new VS 2022, paired, my iphone 12  came up (it's hooked to macbook) and hit run, get those 2 errors... Might have to see versions from old pc and replicate on new laptop. Seem Visual Sudio update and xcode update must have screwed something up. Thanks for responding

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT rebuild from right click on ios project deletes create bin/iphone/debug folder but never sticks anything in it... Like there's and error somewhere but VS isn't showing it to me...

Comment: May i ask the XCode version? Is it XCode 14.2?

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT yes latest 14.2

Comment: I’m afraid that XCode14.2 is not supported yet.  You could try using XCode14.1

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT aight, was gonna try to go back to 13 but will roll back to 14.1 and try again, thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 14.2 is still working on and it's not supported yet. You could check the release note here [Visual Studio 2022 version 17.4.3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-notes#1743--visual-studio-2022-version-1743).

As a workaround, you could now try downgrading back to Xcode 14.1 and build the project. If you still have questions, feel free to ask.

Hope it works for you.

Comment: I did revert back to 14.1 and same issue. I renamed the solution/projects, manafest, assemblies etc. Basically did a find and replace FloridaPlatApp to FloridaPlat, rebuilt, same thing, except it's still looking for FloridaPlatApp which I have no idea where it's still getting reference to that name anymore, everything renamed...

Comment: So anyway I created new solution called FLPApp and it builds and opens app on my iPhone 12, so something F'd up on that solution. Moving classes etc over one by one now to new solution. Be faster than trying to figure out what's hanging onto the FLoridaPLatApp name and looking for it when it's not the name.. :-) thanks for your help...